# Swift 3: unexpected call of applicationDidBecomeBackground after start

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

Im facing a problem with Xcode after switching from Swift 2 to Swift 3 when I compile my app. When I call the Simulator it starts and right after the init screen appears, I get the message "applicationDidBecomeBackground" without any other information. 
I am using Xcode 8.3.3 and LaunchScreen.xib. To be honest I am a bit lost why this happens after changing from swift 2 to 3. 
Any help is much appreciated.

[image: General Part]

[image: This is the message I've got]

Comment: I've added above a screenshot from Xcode. Might it be that there are still old binaries used?

Comment: can you please cleean the build (Command + K) the force quit xxcode (Command + Q). then restart xcode and try again? This happened to me once. (PS: uninstall the application from your simulator, using (Command + H) to go to the homescreen of the simulator and uninstall

Comment: You should test on a real device and see if the issue still exists. Simulator doesn't behave in the exact same way as the real device in all scenarios.

Comment: Hi, I've cleaned the build folder uninstalled the app also I've test the app on my iPad Pro but unfortunately in both cases the behavior is the same, I get the message ...."1.1: error: 2 sending the breakpoint request
warning: failed to set breakpoint site at 0x102201d for breakpoint 1.1: error: 2 sending the breakpoint request
applicationDidBecomeBackground called"